# Celery best way for callback after 1M tasks

Tags: docker-compose, redis, celery, chord

I'm working with **Celery 5.2.7** and **Redis 4.4.0** in a single node docker-compose cluster and was wonder what's the best way to trigger a **finalizer task** after a bunch of **1M** simple, but long lasting **tasks** have completed?
The tasks would have a single integer as input and no output at all.
Can this be done with **Chord**?
Or are there better solutions, since I have read about memory issues that limit the amount of tasks in a chord...
How would I create such a task object, as examples are just dealing with `range(100)`?
BTW, I work on a 24 core machine with 128GB RAM.

Comment: I have found the 'add_to_chord()' (https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#add_to_chord) method, which seems to make it easier filling the header with 1M tasks, but a small example would save a lot of time

Comment: Can add_to_chord() avoid creating a large array of 1M signatures as input for chord?